# Is there a way to compare a generic type (template) with a concrete type in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, generics

I stumbled upon a problem concerning templates and generic types.
What I want to do is the following:

```
template <typename T>
Log& operator<<(const T &stream) {
    buffer_.stream << stream;

    if(stream == "\n")     //Pseudocode
        write(buffer_);

    return *this;
}
```

basically I want to check if the generic argument stream is equal to "\n", but the compiler keeps throwing errors. I tried casting (static) but the compiler doesn't like that either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you use this function, or how do you want to use the function? What do you pass to the function? You might have to make a non-generic overload for strings or characters.

Comment: Might be a obviously good idea to post both the error and what you do instead of omitting the relevant information (the compiler error) and the source (what you've replaced by "Pseudocode").

Comment: Templates don't let you write code you can't write normally with that type.

Comment: C++11 support on your compiler? (ie, relatively recent version of gcc or clang?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution that worked for me:

```
template <typename T>
Log& operator<<(const T &stream) {
    std::ostringstream check;
    buffer_.stream << stream;
    check << stream;
    if(!check.str().compare("\0"))
        write(buffer_);

    return *this;
}
```

The `std::ostringstream` instance is doing the formatting and returns a valid representation of the stream content as a `std::string` with `str()` .
What **didn't worked**:

Overloading the operator<< with another declaration f.e.:

```
    Log& operator<<(const char* stream) {
        buffer_.stream << stream;
        if(!strcmp(stream, "\n"))
           write(buffer_);
        return *this;
    }
```

since the templated overload will be compiled first.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your `T` type. Generally, the whole magic behind templates is that you kind of just fill in the the type as soon as you use the template for the first time; thus, if your compiler throws errors, it's because for the `T` you use, your comparison doesn't work.